# Деактивировать кнопку на время выполнения цикла.

Tags: java, android

При нажатии на кнопку в активити запускается последовательность таймеров с распознаванием голоса. Проблема в том, что при распознавании я снова могу нажать на эту кнопку и она параллельно запустить новый процесс. Как деактивировать кнопку на время выполнения этого цикла?

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.car);

    ImageButton imageButton= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);//кнопка
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


    Timer timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            MediaPlayer voice = MediaPlayer.create(PresentContReading.this, R.raw.ru_1_1);
            voice.start();
            voice.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer voice) {
                    voice.release();
                    Timer timer = new Timer("1");
                    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "You may speak!");
                            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
                            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
                            //int timerId=Integer.parseInt(Thread.currentThread().getName()); //получаем идентификатор таймера
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 1); //засылаем его в Intent
                        }
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0);

        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> results;
        results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        TextView speechText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            str += results.get(i);
        }
        if (str.equals("mercedes")) {
            speechText.setText(str);
            playerFirstRusTwo();//запускает второй рус аудиофайл
        } else {
            speechText.setText(str);
            playerFirstEngOne();// запускает первый англ аудиофайл
        }
    }
            break;
            case 2:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    ArrayList<String> results;
                    results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    TextView speechText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    String str = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                        str += results.get(i);
                    }
                if (str.equals("ford")) {
                    speechText.setText(str);
                    playerFirstRusThree();
                } else {
                    speechText.setText(str);
                    playerFirstEngTwo();
                }
        }
                break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {}` лочить кнопку, вызывая `setClickable(false)`/`setEnabled(false)`.

После завершения процесса распознавания вызывать на кнопке `setClickable(true)`/`setEnabled(true)`.

Comment: @Survitruf http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/492165/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-assets