# Как брать ресурсы из assets

Tags: java, android

На данный момент беру `.mp3` файлы из папки `res/`, но для удобства, я хочу их отсортировать по вложенным папкам, для этого, как я понял, нужно использовать папку `assets/`, но не совсем понимаю, как прописать это в коде.
Создал её в `menu` через `New/Folder/Assets Folder`, но меняя `raw` на `getAssets()` столкнулся с подчеркиванием (код ниже).

Как правильно прописывать ресурсы из `assets`?

```
      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.car);

        ImageButton imageButton= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);//кнопка
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


        Timer timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MediaPlayer voice = MediaPlayer.create(PresentContReading.this, R.raw.ru_1_1);

//Вместо R.raw.ru_1_1 пытаюсь вставить getAssets().open("ford/ford_1.mp3"),
//но тогда вся строчка выделяется красным.

                voice.start();

....................
```

Comment: а зачем вам брать медиа файлы из папки assets? Для этого есть папка raw.

Comment: если у меня их как минимум 200, становится достаточно неудобно их все держать в одной папке.

Comment: попробуйте create через Uri, типа так `MediaPlayer.create(PresentContReading.this, Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/mymp3/play1.mp3"));`

Answer (score 2):

Ваш плеер не занет, что это .`mp3`, так как `assets` это единственное место ресурсов где файлы ещё так сказать не имеют формата, мало того вы используйте метод, который не предназначен для этого. Вам студия должна красиво на это намекать)

Необходимо преобразовать файл, и подгрузить его в ваш плеер. Для преобразования `assets` выступает `AssetManager` для чтения как потока байтов, так будет сделать правильно, создать поток и подгружать(преобразовывать) нужные файлы, но существует более простой(короткий) способ распространенный в сети, используя класс soundpool имеющий дескриптор именно для звуков, у этого метода будут свои минусы. Пример:

```
//Играть
public void playAudio() {
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = context.getAssets().openFd(fileName);
        mp.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(),descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        descriptor.close();
        mp.prepare();
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.setVolume(3, 3);
        mp.start();


    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
//Стоп
public void stop() {
    mp.stop();
   }
}
```

mp это ваш плеер, context это Context, fileName это нужный файл "String"